# How can I cite interviews for radio and TV on CV?

Tags: citations, cv, research-dissemination

I have many contributions related to interviews in radio, TV, web magazines and print magazines, and would like to know the different ways it might be "cited" in a scientific CV. I was thinking about adding them at the end of my CV is some section called "dissemination of research results" or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Interview section in your CV

If you have significant amount of interviews or you want to bring them in your CV, I did not find any special tip to bring interviews in a separate section; but you can open a section like `media appearance/interviews` and list your interviews in this section.

### Citation style

By [googling your question](https://www.google.com/search?&q=interview%20citation), I found many related links in which the citation of the interviews are clearly presented. I bring some of them here for you. One may find a good resource for citation of interviews in [bibme website](http://www.bibme.org). In this website, you will find the format, examples and notes on correct citation.

### [MLA](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/MLA/interview)

> **PUBLISHED/BROADCAST INTERVIEW:**
>   Last Name, First Name. Interview by First Name Last Name. Publication Information. Medium.
>
> **PERSONALLY CONDUCTED INTERVIEW:**
>   Last Name, First Name. Interview Type interview. Date Interviewed.

### [Chicago](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/Chicago/interview)

> **PUBLISHED INTERVIEW FROM PUBLICATION:**
>   Last Name, First Name. Interview with First Name Last Name. Publication Title. Publication Information.
>
> **PUBLISHED INTERVIEW FROM RADIO/TV PROGRAM:**
>   Last Name, First Name. Interview with First Name  Last Name. Program Title. Network, Call letters, Date Interviewed.
>
> **UNPUBLISHED INTERVIEW:**
>   Last Name, First Name. Interview by First Name Last Name. Interview Type. Location, Date Interviewed.

### [Turabian](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/Turabian/interview)

> **UNPUBLISHED INTERVIEW:**   Last Name, First Name. Interview by First Name Last Name. Interview Type. Location, Date Interviewed.

### [APA](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/APA/interview)

Although, in the above link, there is no guide for citing in APA format, as indicated `Interviews are not supported in bibliographies by APA. Please cite it as an in-text citation.`, but I have found the following guide in the [apastyle](http://www.apastyle.org) website for [citation of interviews](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/cite-interview.aspx).

> An interview is not considered recoverable data, so no reference to
>   this is provided in the reference list. You may, however, cite the
>   interview within the text as a personal communication.

### How to easily cite your documents?

By the way, I encourage you to use the softwares like [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net), [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org) and [Endnote](http://endnote.com) to prepare your citations and resources. Also you may use some online websites like [easybib](http://www.easybib.com/mla-format/interview-citation) and [citethisforme](http://citethisforme.com) for easier preparation of your citations.

Answer (score 14):

"Media Appearances" sounds better to me. Then I think I'd cite each appearance as if it were a conference talk:

> "How to Solve the Problem of Evil," *WFUV Radio,* 29 February 1904.

or

> "Why I am So Clever," *The Today Show,* National Broadcasting Corporation, 9 August 1999.

Maybe insert some descriptive language if the citation is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

I advice you use this citing tool at http://www.calvin.edu/library/knightcite/

If it shows an error search for knightcite in their search bar...the tool helps you cite your work properly

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the link you provided - "Document Not Found (404)".

Comment: In general link only answers are discouraged since when the link dies, as it has here, the answer is useless. Can you tell us why the software you are suggesting is a good answer to the question.

Comment: Read my post again...if there is an error search for it in their search bar