# Should I mention a magazine article written about my research in my CV?

Tags: research-process, cv, online-publication, research-dissemination

How does getting into non-submission based magazines appear?  For instance, if R&D magazine took an article about my work (NOT an actual research paper) and published it in their magazine, would this be something I would want to mention on my CV/résumé or would I even bother listing it at all?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "non-submission-based." Presumably you *submit* the article to the magazine, right?

Comment: No.  R&D magazine does not accept submissions.  They find science they like published elsewhere and then write about it on their website.  I'm pretty sure R&D is well-known though.

Comment: Related: [How to cite interviews for radio and TV on CV](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27330/how-to-cite-interviews-for-radio-and-tv-on-cv)

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether the piece published in R&D was actually written by you, or was written by someone else (one of their reporters / contributers) on the subject of your work.  In the former case you could put it on your CV (with some notation that it is not peer reviewed); in the latter you should not, because it wasn't written by you.

Comment: @NateEldredge True, but I have certainly seen something like "has appeared numerous times in TV and print media" in CVs, presumably to indicate wide impact of one's work.

Comment: It depends on where you are applying to. You should mention it in your CV if you think it would impress the hiring committee. It seems unlikely that mentioning it would work against you.

Answer (score 4):

I saw some researcher having "media coverage" or "general impact" columns in their CVs, see e.g. [this example](http://complex.ffn.ub.es/~mbogunya/cv.php#media).

Other way to go (which I do) is to append to the respective publications "featured by [The Economist/Technology Review/2014 Highlights of [this journal]/John Smith's blog]".

IMHO as long you are not overdoing it, it should be a plus.

Answer (score 2):

An article about your research in a broad, application-oriented journal certainly highlights the application potential of your research, and this would be something that you want to show in most applications also for academic positions.

However, I'm not sure how this could be integrated well within an academic CV. Usually you also have a research statement that describes your research activities, and I think it might fit better there. You could generally discuss the (potential) practical impact of your research, and then cite such an article to support your statement.

If such an article would refer to a specific research paper you published, it may also be an option to mention it in your publication list as "*featured by ...*".

Answer (score 2):

I think the key lies in what you mean by "your CV". I personally have a master file for my CV which includes all kinds of information I consider is useful to highlight my person and my work in a wide sense. I then pick and chose from this file to tailor for the specific use and limitations that come up.

So my answer to you will be: *it depends*. You need to consider what may be useful for each time you are required to provide a CV. In many cases, publications in a popular science context can be considered quite valuable whereas they may not be in other cases. I therefore recommend you to consider keeping a master file where you add the sort of publications you refer to under some appropriate heading. You can then decide if you want to add these in the particular case. If you end up with lots of low impact reports etc. you can consider shortening a list to a sentence stating, for example, that you have written X articles in popular science for the following journals: Journal , Journal Y etc.

So, make sure you save all kinds of positive outcomes you have from your work and carefully select what you submit in the end. A single popular science article may not excite many (depending on publishing venue) but if you aggregate a more substantial list over time, it shows your interest to share science with the general public which is sought after with, particularly, (public) funding agencies.